# assert_equal in Ruby have text error

Tags: ruby

i do test in ruby but get false message , but expected is true.
i try give message '1' and in test give '1' but have error.
What i do wrong ?
test code

```
assert_equal('Klient nr 1: Jan Kowalski, stan konta: 0 PLN', c1.to_s)
```

my code

```
def to_s()
    puts "Klient nr #{@p.nr}: #{@p.name} #{@p.surname}, stan konta: #{self.balance} PLN"
end
```

and have screen

[image: error]

Comment: Give us more information on where this is called from. As far as it looks, c1 isn't an object or doesn't correctly respond to `to_s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your to_s method is printing the string, but it's not actually *returning* the string. Instead, it's returning nil, which is definitely not equal to your expected string.

Change it to return the string and you should be good:

```
def to_s()
    return "Klient nr #{@p.nr}: #{@p.name} #{@p.surname}, stan konta: #{self.balance} PLN"
end
```